# How to remove black background after resizing BufferedImages java

Tags: java, transparency, bufferedimage, image-resizing

I wrote a method to resize BufferedImages for me but after doing so .png images end up losing their transparency and instead they get a black background.

```
public BufferedImage getSizedImg(BufferedImage otherImage,int width,int height){
    BufferedImage outputImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics g = outputImg.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(otherImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();
    return outputImg;
}
```

How can I fix the method so that the images keep their transparency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple. When you create your new re-sized BufferedImage here:

```
BufferedImage outputImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

don't use `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` but rather `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`. The `"A"` stands for "alpha" and this gives you the transparency. For more on this, please see the [BufferedImage API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

Comment: So simple yet so impossible to fix unless you know what you are looking for. Thank you.